# how to create nested file system in AIX

Tags: mount, aix

We run an AIX database server.

Our DB team is looking at this configuration:

- `hdisk6` to have a mount point of `/u02/app/oradata/hisdb`
- `hdisk7` to have a mount point of `/u02/app/oradata/hisdb/rmirror`

will the nested filesystem be the correct way to handle this? If so, how can this be done?

Comment: We can't answer without knowing what you're trying to do, and what result you're expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a problem, all file system are indirectly 'nested' off the / filesystem. Just make sure you mount the base hisdb filesystem before you mount rmirror (via the ordering in /etc/filesystems).
However, it would be "cleaner" to mount completely separate off the root, if you ever need to umount the hisdb file system you'd need to umount rmirror first.

Answer (score 1):

A "nested" filesystem isn't the correct way to handle this (or more accurately, it's a funny term for the correct way to handle this).
A *separate* filesystem is what your Oracle admins are asking you to do:

- Create a filesystem on `hdisk6` mounted at `/u02/app/oradata/hisdb`
- Create a filesystem on `hdisk7` mounted at `/u02/app/oradata/hisdb/rmirror`

As HampusLi pointed out this means you must mount `/u02/app/oradata/hisdb` before you mount `/u02/app/oradata/hisdb/rmirror`, and unmount in the reverse order (which will be handled for you if you create the filesystems using `smit` or `smitty`)

What they're not saying explicitly is that `hisdb` and the `hisdb/rmirror` space should be on separate disk spindles - mostly for performance reasons - but it's implicit in the fact that the filesystems exist on two different disk devices.